# Browse files WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm developing an application to Windows Phone 7. The user needs to select a file from his phone (images, office files, files from skydrive, etc).

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot browse the root filesystem of a WP7 device at this time. You **can** browse and allow the user to select [files from Skydrive](http://wp7skydrive.codeplex.com/) and [pictures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394019%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) from the media library, however.

Comment: It's really too bad :( Thanks by your answer

Comment: @rpf If you feel this answered your question adequately, please accept it as an answer so people who come by later will know it as such.

Comment: I know... i'm just waiting if appear some new answers ;)

Comment: There are no other answers to get. Ananthonline's answer is the correct one. Also, if another answer appears that you like better, you can unselect one that was previously selected, and select the new one.